# How to use @Subscribe annotation on Xamarin.Forms Android platform using Greenrobot.EventBus package

Tags: android, xamarin, subscriber

I am trying to implement EventBus on Xamarin but Could not able to Subscribe the Events because when I am adding the annotation @Subscribe(), I am getting an error "@Subscribe does not exist in the current context". And when I am running the Application without @Subscribe annotation, it is showing me an Error saying "MainActivity and its super classes have no public-methods with the @Subscribe annotation". Please help me on how to subscribe the Event on Xamarin Android platform

#MainActivity class:

```
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
           //Registering Event Bus here
            EventBus.Default.Register(this);
       
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
        }
        
        @Subscribe //Showing me an error while adding this annotation
        public void OnEvent(NetworkInfo networkInfo)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(networkInfo);
        }

        protected void OnDestroy()
        {
            base.OnDestroy();
            EventBus.Default.Unregister(this);
        }
    }

PublisherEvent class:
public class PublishEvent 
    {
      public PublishEvent()
      { 
         EventBus.getDefault().post(message);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether Xamarin Forms supports **EventBus**, and uses `@Subscribe()` as the same with native Android.

However, there is a same way in Xamarin Forms. You could use **[Xamarin.Forms MessagingCenter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center)** to achieve that, it also can subscribe the message and receive message.

Send Messaage:

```
MessagingCenter.Send<object>(this, "Hi");
```

Subscribe Message:

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<object> (this, "Hi", (sender) =>
{
    // Do something whenever the "Hi" message is received
});
```

Comment: Hi, Actually I am trying to establish communication between Xamarin and android code(Java) in aar(Static library).MessagingCenter works on Xamarin only. Do you know other alternatives for communication between java and Xamarin?Thanks.

Comment: @ZahraW If you have been [binding an .AAR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/binding-an-aar), it will needs you to expose methods from Java, then can communicate between them.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get `Subscribe` to work via Xamarin

I noticed your code here

```
@Subscribe //Showing me an error while adding this annotation
public void OnEvent(NetworkInfo networkInfo)
{
    Console.WriteLine(networkInfo);
}
```

was this implemented as follows? (note the use of attributes rather than the java annotation)

```
[Subscribe] 
public void OnEvent(NetworkInfo networkInfo)
{
    Console.WriteLine(networkInfo);
}
```

In order for this to work, Android needs to convert the `Subscribe` attribute to the `@Subscribe` Annotation in Java. The Xamarin Binding Library *should* be creating `SubscribeAttribute` for you if you've got that project setup correctly (though it may notably be missing the `ThreadMode` property, I may be investigating that for myself soon!)

Anyways, this attribute won't be correctly generated if the `OnEvent` method isn't also generated in the corresponding Java class. I found this did not happen automatically for me so I simply needed to add `[Export]` to the method.

```
[Export]   
[Subscribe] 
public void OnEvent(NetworkInfo networkInfo)
{
    Console.WriteLine(networkInfo);
}
```

This is actually (somewhat unobviously) documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/java-integration/working-with-jni#annotation-attribute)